# How to avoid the nullable reference types in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been working on a project at work where I do not run into many null warnings and it is ASP.NET Core 5 I believe however I started a new project recently and decided to go with ASP.NET Core 7 and I am not sure why but I keep running into warnings related to nullable (CS8602 typically). I now find myself having to add if then statements to check if the variable is null or not. What am I doing wrong in this new version of .net? Its increasing my code side susbtantially I feel like. I have included a sample excerpt of my code below and as you will see if I removed a if(blah == null) then usage of that object would then become a warning for possible null. This snippet of code is for a contact us form and to implement a recaptcha on the front end (aka the token).

```
namespace Chesapeake_Tees_API.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ContactUsController : ControllerBase
{

private readonly ILogger<ContactUsController> _logger;
private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
private readonly string? reCaptchaKey = "";

public ContactUsController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<ContactUsController> logger, IEmailService emailService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _emailService = emailService;
    reCaptchaKey = configuration["CFTunrstileSecretKey"];
}

[HttpPost(Name = "PostContactUs")]
[EnableRateLimiting("api")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] CustomerInquiry customerInquiry)
{
    try
    {
        if (reCaptchaKey != null && customerInquiry.Token != null)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "secret", reCaptchaKey },
                    { "response", customerInquiry.Token }
                };

            var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary);

            HttpResponseMessage? recaptchaResponseHTTP = null;
            string? reCaptchaResponseJSON;

            // Call recaptcha api and validate the token
            using (var http = new HttpClient())
            {
                recaptchaResponseHTTP = await http.PostAsync("https://challenges.cloudflare.com/turnstile/v0/siteverify", postContent);
                reCaptchaResponseJSON = await recaptchaResponseHTTP.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            var reCaptchaResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ReCaptchaResponse>(reCaptchaResponseJSON);

            if (recaptchaResponseHTTP.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (reCaptchaResponse == null)
                {
                    return Ok($"Message: Error code 503, unable to verify reCaptcha token");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (reCaptchaResponse.Success)
                    {
                        EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();

                        emailMessage.From = new Contact { DisplayName = "Chesapeake Tees", EmailAddress = "site@chesapeaketees.com" };
                        emailMessage.To.Add(new Contact { DisplayName = "Chesapeake Tees", EmailAddress = "info@chesapeaketees.com" });
                        emailMessage.ReplyTo = new Contact { DisplayName = customerInquiry.FirstName + " " + customerInquiry.LastName, EmailAddress = customerInquiry.EmailAddress };
                        emailMessage.Subject = "Custome Inquiry";
                        emailMessage.Body = customerInquiry.Message;
                        await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(emailMessage);
                        return Ok("Message: Success - email sent");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string? errors = null;

                        if (reCaptchaResponse.ErrorCodes != null)
                        {
                            errors = string.Join(",", reCaptchaResponse.ErrorCodes);
                        }
                        return Ok($"Message: Error code 500, {errors}");

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok($"Message: Error code 503, unable to verify reCaptcha token");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok($"Message: Error code 503, unable to verify reCaptcha token");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Message: Error: " + ex.ToString(), DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());
        throw;
    }
}
}
```

The model I am using which I have included ? to make them nullable (setting a default value to something doesnt seem to solve my warnings for the parent class itself but maybe the one property) includes the following:

```
    public class ReCaptchaResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("cdata")]
    public string? CData { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("challenge_ts")]
    public DateTime ChallengeTs { get; set; } // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)

    [JsonPropertyName("hostname")]
    public string? HostName { get; set; }    // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved

    [JsonPropertyName("error-codes")]
    public string[]? ErrorCodes { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerInquiry
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = "";

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; } = "";

    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; } = "";

    [Required]
    public string Token { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: `using (var http = new HttpClient())` - do not instantiate http clients manually, use DI with `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: What is `reCaptchaKey`?

Comment: Sorry added additional part of code. Its the secret key from recaptcha but again it gave a warning saying it could be null despite my configuration/appsetting is not going to have a null value in there. More nullable warnings leading to a ton of nested if not null statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can disable NRTs (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts)) either completely (`<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in csproj) or partially (`#nullable disable`)
2. Do not specify the empty strings for properties, you can use the new [`required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) keyword which I would argue is a nicer alternative:

```cs
public class CustomerInquiry
{
    [Required]
    public required string FirstName { get; set; } 
    // ... 
}
```

3. `customerInquiry.Token != null` is not needed from nullable analysis standpoint since `Token` is declared as non-nullable.
4. Do not declare variables as nullable when not needed:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage recaptchaResponseHTTP;
string reCaptchaResponseJSON;

// Call recaptcha api and validate the token
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
    // PostAsync returns non-nullable HttpResponseMessage wrapped in task
    recaptchaResponseHTTP = await http.PostAsync("https://challenges.cloudflare.com/turnstile/v0/siteverify", postContent);
    // ReadAsStringAsync returns non-nullable string wrapped in task
    reCaptchaResponseJSON = await recaptchaResponseHTTP.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

recaptchaResponseHTTP.ToString(); // no warning
```

Also as I wrote in the comment - do not instantiate http clients manually, use DI with `IHttpClientFactory` which will make the using obsolete and you can use inline assignment.

4. Use operators helping with nullability for example the [null-coalescing operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```cs
if (reCaptchaResponse.Success)
{
   // ...
}
else
{  
    string errors =  string.Join(",", reCaptchaResponse.ErrorCodes ?? new List<...>());
    return Ok($"Message: Error code 500, {errors}");
}
```

5. This depends on the app logic but I would argue that missing recaptcha key from the config is an error and you should fail fast in ctor:

```cs
private readonly string reCaptchaKey = "";

public ContactUsController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<ContactUsController> logger, IEmailService emailService)
{
    var captchaKey = configuration["CFTunrstileSecretKey"];
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(captchaKey);
    reCaptchaKey = captchaKey;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to used the [Required] tag with the required initiator before the declaration or just the declaration? Whats the difference as its solving my issue.

Comment: @IrishRedneck `RequiredAttribute` is not considered by the compiler in null state analysis, while `required` modifier is (see the linked in answer docs). `RequiredAttribute` annotation is used by (at least some) validators and binders to validate incoming model. `required` modifier is enforced by compiler and is used by validators/binders.

Comment: This was extremely helpful and I have learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: I was curious of one thing for my code above. In all those scenarios where things fail like the null recaptcha key, or maybe the key is invalid and it returns a response which my if then catches. Should I still be returning Ok() which returns 200 code with a message saying 503 error or should the response actually be throwing an exception such as 503 using return StatusCode(503)?

Comment: @IrishRedneck it depends on the requirements. But as rule of thumb you should not return `Ok` with message "error...", if you have an error you should return the corresponding error code optionally supplying it with an extra message.